# My background image is being corrupted in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, transform

Using Chrome 27 with win 7 and on an asus UX31 series laptop (and also tried it on a mac book pro). I visit my page, http://ezimerchant.com/dev. Scroll down and scroll up again. Then I can see this: http://www.bounceapp.com/99549. Note the background image on the carousel is half missing.

note: Some of you may not be able to see the issue possibly because your video card is better than mine?

**What I've tried**

- Setting `transform:none; -webkit-transform:none` to the `#carousel-container` element, which is the one that has the background container. Same problem.
- Adding a `translateZ(0) translate3d(0,0,0)` to the `#carousel-container`. Same problem.
- Doing the above to `#carousel-container *, #carousel-container`. Same problem.

Does anyone else have some ideas of what I can do? I am operating under the assumption that the background image needs to become part of the rendering pipeline to ensure that it won't corrupt - because the transforms happen to the images that are absolutely positioned ontop of the background (the words and the ipad).

Thoughts?
Thanks.

Comment: http://www.bounceapp.com/99550

Comment: You're quite right - I can't see the problem in FF21 or Google Chrome 29.0.1535.3. This looks a hardware specific problem - how many machines have you tried it on?

Comment: if you reset this property it gets fixed: #carousel-container{ background-position: center top !important;
    }

Comment: @vals What do you mean "reset". I tried applying it, and then turning it on and off but the issue still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
.carousel .item {
height: 550px;
position: relative;
}
```

To this:

```
.carousel .item {
height: 550px;
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This is interesting, it doesn't solve the problem - however - If I change the positioning from relative to something else and then back again it looks good. Until another scroll then it dies again. This looks like a good way to force a refresh.